# Facebook PHP SDK getUser() CKR_DEVICE_ERROR

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, sdk

I have used the Facebook PHP SDK to create a Facebook-login for my webpage. And it worked as it should.

Some time between yesterday and last thursday it suddenly stopped working. No changes have been made to the code. To root out any errors I might have made I created a testing script, with only the basics for logging in - actually just copied the login-example from the SDK.

This script showed the same problem. A bit of digging here on StackOverflow gave me the idea to print the array from the exception thrown in fundtion getAccessTokenFromCode() in base_facebook.php.

The array contains this:

```
FacebookApiException Object ( 
                [result:protected] => Array ( 
                [error_code] => 35 
                [error] => Array ( 
                        [message] => A PKCS #11 module returned CKR_DEVICE_ERROR, indicating that a problem has occurred with the token or slot. 
                        [type] => CurlException 
                       ) 
                ) 
                [message:protected] => A PKCS #11 module returned CKR_DEVICE_ERROR, indicating that a problem has occurred with the token or slot. 
                [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 35
```

I'm simply at a loss here about where to look, so any hints or help would be appreciated a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Oh happy day!

The server was running a Fedora 19. I noticed that I could not update to the latest version of CURL, so just to root out any possibilities I decided to update to Fedora 20.

And this fixed the problem. I'm guessing something broke in the old version of CURL, and was only fixed in the Fedora 20 available version.